# How to remove code structure view or "breadcrumbs" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While I was working on visual studio code, I accidentally hit a key with the command and it somehow brought into view this

[image: this]

and I'm trying to get rid of it but can't seem to find anything on it.

I'm using a Mac, using version 1.27.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are "breadcrumbs"and can be disabled by:

```
"breadcrumbs.enabled": false
```

in your settings.  That is set to true by default.

There are a couple more breadcrumb settings you might look at to see if like how it looks better:

```
"breadcrumbs.filePath": "last"

"breadcrumbs.symbolPath": "on"
```