# Hide file drop down menu in editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in VS Code and (I think I used a wrong shortcut) the following feature appeared: When having a file opened in a tab, there appears a bar below the header of the tab and above the first line of the file. When clicking on it, a dropdown menu opens up, where one can select the other files of the current folder (see picture below). When clicking on one of them, this file is opened in a new tab.
How can i remove this menu? I already searched through my user and workspace settings, but didn't find an appropriate option.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvXr5.png)

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing code structure view - breadcrumbs - in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507961/removing-code-structure-view-breadcrumbs-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled VSCode's [breadcrumb](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs) feature.  To disable it:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command pallete.
2. Type "Toggle Breadcrumbs" and press enter.

Alternatively, you can disable the breadcrumbs from the settings menu:

[image]