# How to show breadcrumbs on Visual studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I made this window disappear. How do I recover it?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide file drop down menu in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576992/hide-file-drop-down-menu-in-editor)

Comment: I made a youtube tutorial for showing/hiding the breadcrumbs if anyone finds it useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9wL9WG8bM

Comment: Thanks alot @Brendan Metcalfe but is it possible to hide both breadcrumbs (that is the path bar) and the tabs bar at the top of the window ? In this video you keep tabs visible. I want to remove everything that's displayed at the top of the window and just have code start below the windows bar (that with the red/yellow/green buttons).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those are called **breadcrumbs** in most IDEs. In VSCode, it's no different.

Find the setting by going to your settings and searching "Breadcrumbs".

[image: Breadcrumbs search in settings]

If you choose to not use the fancy settings editor, you can manually add this to your configuration:

```
"breadcrumbs.enabled": true
```

#### Update

As of May 2019 (version 1.35), breadcrumbs are enabled by default in VSCode. They can still be toggled using the steps outlined above.

Answer (score 5):

Beware that even if you have breadcrumbs turned on in settings and the Language is selected, you will have to save the file in order to get breadcrumbs in VS Code 1.52.1
[image: readcrumbs not shown because the file is not saved yet]

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add one more thing to Ian MacDonalds answer:

---

You can simply toggle them within the **"View"**-menu `View > Appearance > Breadcrumbs` :

[image]

[Old image for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyBmu.png)

Comment: I don't see Toggle Breadcrumbs ... Is it something we have to enable?

Comment: @Ole did you have a look if they are enabled in the settings? (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957377 )

Comment: Yes I have them toggled on, I just don't see the ability to toggle them on and off in the View menu ... Maybe it's because I'm on MacOS ...

Comment: @Ole Indeed! It is not becasue of Apple (no ThanksApple this time ;). I did not notice but you are right. The UI was changed and they moved into a sub-menu of View > Appearance. I have updated the post for your convenience.

Comment: OH Cool!!  I see it now!  Good catch!