# How to remove in file navigator?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to look in the preferences setting I couldn't find anything. Moreover, I don't know how did these got activated in the first place. Here is an image of what I refer to:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide file drop down menu in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576992/hide-file-drop-down-menu-in-editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled through the `Breadcrumbs` settings. In order to activate/deactivate it follow these steps:

1. Open Settings with `Ctrl+,`.
2. Search for `Breadcrumbs`.
3. Enable or disable the option `Breadcrumbs: Enabled`.

It can also be activated/deactivated by editing the `settings.json` file adding or deleting the following line:

```
"breadcrumbs.enabled": true
```