# How to hide directory/function path top bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to hide directory/function path top bar in VSCode

[image: top bar]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing code structure view - breadcrumbs - in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507961/removing-code-structure-view-breadcrumbs-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I made a youtube tutorial for showing/hiding the breadcrumbs if anyone finds it useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9wL9WG8bM

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is breadcrumbs option. From `Preferences -> Settings`, type `breadcrumb` in text box until seeing the options below and uncheck the `Breadcrumbs` option to disable it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me. Although i've seen videos where it does. I've tried disabling "Show Breadcrumbs" in the "View" menu too, and the only thing it does is show "~/Desktop" as path in the path bar instead of the full path+filename. Anyone has had that behavior ? I'm on macOS ventura, with the latest stable VSC. Thank you.

Comment: So i understood the following: 1 can now hide the path bar but i must have the tabs bar visible, 2 if i try then hiding the tabs bar the path bar reappears. Do you see the same behavior ? I just want to hide everything but the windows bar (with the red/orange/green buttons) at the top of the window. Anyone can do this on their macOS, or some other OS ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

This top bar is called "breadcrumbs". You can disable it in the visual user settings editor by unticking the checkbox or adding this line to your JSON config:

```
// settings.json
{
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
}
```

Comment: As stated in my comment to deerawan above, this does not work for me. I still have the path bar, only showing path ~/Desktop instead of /Users/plm/Desktop/py.py for instance for the file i'm having open now. I have screenshots but how can i post them here ? Thank you very much. I've just installed VSC, i've ne changed many settings apart from hiding the clutter -sidebar, statusbar, and scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

From the `View` menu, uncheck `✔ Show Breadcrumbs`.